# jQuery imgZoomAndRotate plugin not working on dynamically loaded images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to integrate jQuery plugin [imgZoomAndRotate](https://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/image-gallery-zoom-rotate-drag-switch.html) in my codeigniter system. When I follow the steps 1-4 as mentioned in the link the library works perfectly fine for static images. But when I try to call a js function to load the images via my database the images are loaded but library doesn't work on clicking the images.

**Static images case**

```
<div class="row row-5" id="images-modules">
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="img-thumbnail rounded"><span class="del-image" data-id="15">&times;</span><img src="<?php echo $equipment_images_path;?>6ff77345db350d4efd50f6573b72164c.jpeg" class="img-fluid"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="img-thumbnail rounded"><span class="del-image" data-id="15">&times;</span><img src="<?php echo $equipment_images_path;?>bbf36b9be6c1f4c40399ec024603a010.JPG" class="img-fluid"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="img-thumbnail rounded"><span class="del-image" data-id="15">&times;</span><img src="<?php echo $equipment_images_path;?>9e4f68c3fd043978295cc359caf2b784.jpeg" class="img-fluid"></div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Dynamic Images Case**

```
<div class="row row-5" id="images-modules">
</div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
<script src="{theme_url}js/plupload/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="{theme_url}js/ezoom/jquery.drag.js"></script>
<script src="{theme_url}js/ezoom/imgZoomAndRotate.js" ></script>
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
   
          function loadImages(){
           $.getJSON('<?php echo base_url($action_url); ?>?load_images=true', function (data) {
               $('#images-modules').html('');
               if (data.length>0){
   
                   $(data).each(function(o,i){
                       
                       $('#images-modules').append('<div class="col-sm-2">'+i.first_name+'<div class="img-thumbnail rounded"><span class="del-image" data-id="'+i.ID+'">&times;</span><img src="<?php echo $equipment_images_path;?>'+i.thumb_filename+'" class="img-fluid"></div></div>');
                   });
               }else{
                   $('#images-modules').html('<div class="alert alert-info">No images associated with this inventory.</div>')
               }
           });
       }
       loadImages();
   
          $('.img-fluid').imgZoomAndRotate({
           'loop':true
         }); 
   });
</script>
```

1. For testing the library with static images I just comment the function `loadImages()` and the library works perfectly fine.
2. For testing the library with dynamic images I just remove all content of div `<div class="row row-5" id="images-modules">` which will be loaded on calling the function `loadImages()` on `document.ready`.
   In 2nd case the images are loaded in the `images-modules` div and displayed in the container but the library is not working when I click the images.

P.S:

There are no JS errors in console as well.
All the JS files are loaded fine without any issue of path

Appreciations in advance

**EDITS**
imgindex= 0,1,2 is not being attached to **img** in case of dynamically loading the images (Library automatically adds this attribute in static images case). I have even tried to attach `imgindex` tag with images dynamically while loading the images but still its not working